# showin alert before app is reloaded by post request (react)

Tags: html, reactjs, axios

after a post request i want to show an alert but the page refresh after the request and the state reset so i cant control it... how can i show an alert after the post request? this is my code the alert here dosent work

```
   async onClick(details) {
        try {
           await axios.post('xxx', details);
           alert('sucess')
        } catch(err) {
           console.log(err)
           alert('faiil')
        }
    }
```

any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Is this `onClick` handler attached to a `submit` button of a `<form>`? If so, you'll want to call `.preventDefault()` on the button's/form's event handler because otherwise the browser will do what form submits normally do - do a request to the form's `action`.

Comment: thanks bro that did it

Answer (score 1):

1. First add your onClick function which will fire when you click the button.
2. Use `event.preventDefault()` to stop page refresh.
3. Then use `.then` in axios request which will work as a binder

   ```
   const onClick = (event,details) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     axios.post('xxx', details)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success) {
                alert('Success')
            } else {
                alert('Failed request')
            }
        })
      }
   ```